# Как реализовать белую рамку вокруг кнопки с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image]

Как реализовать белую рамку вокруг кнопки с помощью CSS

Comment: она анимированная?

Comment: нет, статическая

Comment: градиентами делайте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На картинке явно просматривается конический градиент:

```css
body { background-color: #6e8591; }

button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1d3a47;
}
button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.2em; left: -0.2em;
  z-index: -1;
  height: calc(100% + 0.4em);
  width: calc(100% + 0.4em);
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-image: conic-gradient(#1d3a47 10%, #ffff);
}
```

```html
<button>ПОДРОБНЕЕ</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-то так / Цвета брал от балды, думаю идея понятна

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  min-width: 110px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff, #000 50%, #000);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

button span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Подробнее</span></button>
```